# joins on polymorphic table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Sellers that sell various types of products (Painting, Song, Book, etc).

I have a purchases table that has a polymorphic product association using product_id, and product_type, where product_type would be of Painting, Song, Book, etc.

I want to do a query for Seller, to get a list of all of their products that have been purchased, but I get this:

Purchase.joins(:product).limit(10).offset(9000)

```
Hirb Error: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :product
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
class Seller < User
  def sales
    Purchase.where("(product_id in (?) AND product_type = 'Book') OR (product_id IN (?) AND product_type = 'Song')", books.collect(&:id), songs.collect(&:id))
  end
end
```

Comment: Please move this "answer" into your question and then delete this. That's the stackoverflow way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state, but you must have something like:

```
class Purchase
  belongs_to :product, :polymorphic => true
end
class Painting
  has_many :purchases, :as => :product
end
class Song
  has_many :purchases, :as => :product
end
class Book
  has_many :purchases, :as => :product
end
```

Since the :product association in the Purchase class is polymorphic, it has no idea what all the tables are which need to be joined in the search.  How would ActiveRecord know to make the join to paintings, songs, and books, but no other tables?  It doesn't know, so it cannot do the join.

Comment: It could look for distinct values in product_type, and infer the tables required. But that probably still wouldn't work. How then would I get a list of purchases for a seller, if the seller_id is not in the purchase table, and I can't do a join? I'm currently doing this per product type, and then combining/sorting via ruby. Not impressive.

Comment: OK, it could know, but won't do the join on different tables like that.

Comment: This answer was that active record won't do this.  You were stumped, and I thought you just needed to know how it worked.  Getting the results is another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you really have multiple table inheritance, you could have a products table with a polymorphic foreign key the each product record in whatever table.  Do the relationships between products, sellers, and purchases using the products table.  If you need the details of a specific project, like book name, dereference the foreign key in products, and get the books record.