# Using dual polymorphism through a join table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to use polymorphism to help reduce duplication in my Rails 4 app, but am not having much luck. Conceptually, I have Computers and I have Printers, both of which I think could be considered Equipment. These items are assigned to either Employees or Facilities, both of which function as Owners. I also need to track chain of custody, so I thought simply adding some datetime fields to a join table would allow me to accomplish what everything I wanted.

Code so far:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :computers, as: :equipment
  has_many   :printers,  as: :equipment
  belongs_to :owners,    polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :computers, as: :equipment
  has_many   :printers,  as: :equipment
  belongs_to :owners,    polymorphic: true
end

class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :equipment,  polymorphic: true
  has_many   :facilities, as: :owners
  has_many   :employees,  as: :owners
end

class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :equipment,  polymorphic: true
  has_many   :facilities, as: :owners
  has_many   :employees,  as: :owners
end

# Join table structure
create_table "equipment_owners", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "equipment_id"
  t.string   "equipment_type"
  t.integer  "owner_id"
  t.string  "owner_type"
  t.datetime "possession_datetime"
  t.datetime "relinquish_datetime"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Most examples of how to use polymorphic associations are singular (i.e. [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) & [Railscast #154](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?view=asciicast)), and so I tried to follow those structures as best I could. Unfortunately, testing the association in Rails console shows errors:

```
irb > Computer.find_by_id(9).facilities
Facility Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "facilities".* FROM "facilities" WHERE "facilities"."owners_id" = ? AND "facilities"."owners_type" = ?  [[nil, 9]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: facilities.owners_id: SELECT "facilities".* FROM "facilities"  WHERE "facilities"."owners_id" = ? AND "facilities"."owners_type" = ?
```

This suggests that I need to tell ActiveRecord to look in the EquipmentOwners table. Unfortunately, if I update my has_many to `has_many :facilities, as: :owners, through: :equipment_owners`, I get the following error:

```
irb > Computer.find_by_id(9).facilities
Computer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "computers".* FROM "computers" WHERE "computers"."id" = 9
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :equipment_owners in model Computer
```

Can anyone suggest a way to make this work, or is this just beyond what I can do using standard Rails associations? Is the answer to make an `equipment_owner_id` in  all of my tables? That seems to sloppy, but it's my only idea currently.

Comment: You need STI, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails

Comment: Even with Models as different as those listed above? The overlap in data fields wtihin each polymorphic group is minimal, even if they end up having similar relationships to the opposite group.

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to do so without STI, you can checkout( even though it is not recommended)
[joins on polymorphic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389246/joins-on-polymorphic-table)